# Linq to Entity Query very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have a LINQ to Entity query that is running really slow.  This query performs some calculation logic on a particular database and then passes the result to a ViewModel.  The query was really fast until I added the 4 select statements at the bottom of the query.  I need the select statements in order to return a collection of the result responses.  Why is the query running so slow like this?

```
  var data = from SurveyResponseModel in db.SurveyResponseModels
                       group SurveyResponseModel by SurveyResponseModel.MemberId into resultCount
                       select new ResultsViewModel()
                       {

                           YesBarriersOthersResult = resultCount.Select(r => r.YesBarriersOthers),
                           NoBarriersOthersResult = resultCount.Select(r => r.NoBarriersOthers),
                           TotalResponsesResult = db.SurveyResponseModels.Count(),
                       };




            return View(data);
```

Comment: I would check the actual SQL commands. Maybe some queries executing several times, or EF created some crazy subquery?

Comment: This is good advice.  I was using SQLCOmpact edition for development, but it seems much faster now after switching to SQL Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard for me to tell you what's exactly wrong here, but having faced similar problems with orms and all, I can suggest that the best way to debug the problem is to find out what sql statements are actually generated and run against the database. A lot of times your ORM could be running too many sql statements to get the same simple result.

Comment: Yes. @[Vishal Kumar] is right. And the best way to check sql statements and its process is to use **SQL Profiler**. If you have it installed it's so easy to create a trace and see what's really going on in SQL side.